# I am having trouble installing angular cli

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I am getting below error while i try to install angular cli. I have updated my node as well as npm but none is working.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting warnings for `fsevents` but `@angular/cli` seems to be installed correctly because there is no error related to it. So check by running `ng help` or `ng new PROJECT_NAME` command of `@angular/cli` to check if it works or not.

Comment: Thank you, looks like i was worried for no reason. Avira was showing virus detection while i was trying to install angular cli, that triggered my fear.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error!
You can ignore those warnings.

fseventsd is an macOS specific package and cannot be installed on Windows (you can see it in the warning 'wanted <"os":"darwin">')

It is an optional packages so that means it's probably only needed on mac since it targets mac.